# jvectormaps with firefox results in unexpected error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jvectormap

I am able to get the map to load without issues with IE 9, however when testing with FF 31 i am unable to get the map to load what so ever. With Firebug, its reporting a

```
 Unexpected value scale(0) translate(Infinity, 0) parsing transform attribute.
```

This seems to be more related to the actual map than my implementation. 
My current implementation is as follows:

```
         $('#map').vectorMap({
        map: 'us_aea_en',
        backgroundColor: "#728DA5",
        onRegionLabelShow: function (e, el, code) {
            el.html(el.html());
        }, onRegionClick: function (event, code) {
            var map = $('#map').vectorMap('get', 'mapObject');
            showAgencies(map.getRegionName(code));
        }
    });
```

I have this map: http://jvectormap.com/js/jquery-jvectormap-us-aea-en.js as the map to use and it is loaded prior to the actual implementation script. Like i said, it works good in IE, with just a little bit of tweaking for the page its on.

I may be missing something small but for the life of me i really don't know where.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved. Well a work around really. The issues is that Jvectormap does not do well with dynamic width and height. i was using a 85% height on the div container. I set this to one, and then in the Java doc ready i use this code to set it to the correct size taking in consideration for other elements

```
 $("#map").css("height", $(document).height() - 120); // Hot fix for cross browser support
```

The resulting pages are not working in IE 9, FF 31, Opera and Chrome without issues.